How to calculate shadow far plane for sphere light?
I've got point-light shadows implemented.
I get the projection matrix like this:
struct PointLight
{
    glm::vec4 colorIntensity;
    glm::vec3 position;
    float radius;
};

glm::mat4 getPointShadowProjection(float radius)
{
    return glm::perspectiveZO(glm::radians(90.0f), 1.0f, 0.01f, radius);
}

far plane is the same as the radius.
and then in shadow fragment shader I also save linearized depth value
gl_FragDepth = length(worldPosition - lightPos) / farPlane;

where far plane is just the light radius.
For distance attenuation with squared inverse radius, it works fine (GLSL):
float getSquareFalloffAttenuation(float distanceSquare, float falloff) 
{
    float factor = distanceSquare * falloff;
    float smoothFactor = saturate(1.0 - factor * factor);
    return smoothFactor * smoothFactor;
}

float getDistanceAttenuation(vec3 posToLight, float falloff) 
{
    vec2 lightFarAttenuationParams = vec2(5.0f, 0.0005f);

    float distanceSquare = dot(posToLight, posToLight);
    float attenuation = getSquareFalloffAttenuation(distanceSquare, falloff);
    highp vec3 v = worldPosition - cameraPosition;
    attenuation *= saturate(lightFarAttenuationParams.x - dot(v, v) * lightFarAttenuationParams.y);
    return attenuation / max(distanceSquare, 1e-4);
}

vec3 CalculateLight(uint lightIndex, PointLight light)
{
    vec3 posToLight = ...;

    float sqFalloff = light.radius * light.radius;
    float squaredFallOffInv = sqFalloff > 0.0f ? (1 / sqFalloff) : 0;
    float attenuation = getDistanceAttenuation(posToLight, squaredFallOffInv);

    float shadow = PointShadow(lightIndex, worldPosition, light.position, light.radius);

    //the rest is not important
    ...
}

uniform samplerCubeArrayShadow u_pointShadowMap;
float PointShadow(uint index, vec3 worldPosition, vec3 lightPos, float radius)
{  
    vec3 fragToLight = worldPosition - lightPos;
    float currentDepth = (length(fragToLight) - 0.05f) / radius;

    return texture(u_pointShadowMap, vec4(fragToLight, index), currentDepth);
}

but I want to use the solid angle instead of distance attenuation:
float CalculateSolidAngle(const float r, const float d)
{
    const float r2 = r * r;
    const float d2 = d * d;
    const float h = 1.0f - sqrt(1.0f - min(r2 / d2, 1.0f));
    return PI_2 * h;
}

vec3 CalculateLight(uint lightIndex, PointLight light)
{
    vec3 posToLight = ...;
  
    float attenuation = CalculateSolidAngle(light.radius, length(posToLight));

    float shadow = PointShadow(lightIndex, worldPosition, light.position, light.radius);

    //the rest is not important
    ...
}

then I cannot just use the radius as a far plane, because it's too small.
How should I then calculate the shadow far plane?
